# How can I create a code between excel and word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a VBA code to do this:

1. Open a dialog box to choose a word file in the path: C:\Add-in\Company A\Templates in docx format
2. Select as active sheet Navette the file: "Checklist - Navette" if there's no open file with this name appear a message: "ERROR Please push the comand checklist first" and quit the macro
3. Populate all the bookmarks of the word file with content cells that have name equal as the bookmarks (use sheet Navette)
4. If the Navette sheet has a cell named "Civilité" and the content is equal to "Female" must go to the excel file in the path: C:\Add-in\Mapping.xlsx on the Replace sheet and search all the words in the column A throught the word file and replace with words in the column B otherwise replace with the words in the column C
5. Open a dialog box to input the path to save the word with the name TEST in word and pdf format
6. Close the initial files without saving
7. Quit all aplications

I'm stucked in the code and it's even working. When I try to run It also get stucked :(

```
Sub TestProcess()

'Initial process
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wdDoc As Document
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim SaveAsFileName As String
    Dim SaveAsFileFormat As Integer
    
'Dialog box to pickup the docx file
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Add-in\Company\Templates"
        .Filters.Add "Word Files", "*.docx", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            strFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(strFile)
    
'Identify the checklist
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks("Company - Navette.xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0

'Handling with errors
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "ERROR 'Please select the command *Open Navette*first"
        wdDoc.Close
        Set wdDoc = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Active Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Navette")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Handling with errors
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet 'Navette' not found in the workbook."
        
        'For each Bookmark equal name cell replace with the content
        
        For Each wdBookmark In wdDoc.Bookmarks
            wdBookmark.Range.Text = ws.Range(wdBookmark.Name).Value
        Next
        
        
        'Save file
        'Open a dialog box to input the path to save the Word file
        SaveAsFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Word Files (*.docx), .docx; PDF Files (.pdf), *.pdf", Title:="Save As", InitialFileName:=strFile)
        
        'Check if a file name and format are selected
        If SaveAsFileName <> "False" Then
            'Determine the selected file format
            If Right(SaveAsFileName, 4) = ".pdf" Then
                SaveAsFileFormat = 17
            Else
                SaveAsFileFormat = 0
            End If
            'Save the file in the selected format
            objDoc.SaveAs SaveAsFileName, FileFormat:=SaveAsFileFormat
        End If
        
        'Close Doc & Excel
        wdDoc.Close
        wb.Close
        
        'Reset the documents
        Set wdDoc = Nothing
        Set wb = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add details about the error you are having, the line that the code stops at or the differences between your current output and your desired output.

Comment: My code stops after selecting the word file. Nothing happens and should happen the points described

Comment: When you indent your code properly, as I did in your post, you can conclude that the main part of your procedure would run only if the `Navette` worksheet would not be found resulting in an error. I would guess there is a missing *Else* statement right after the message box at the beginning.

Comment: I'm getting OLE error Excel is waiting for another application to end. Already search for this error in the web and have tried to change the steps but nothing changes. I deleted and tried... and the problem is when running the word that I select

Comment: In which application (Word or Excel) are you running this code? If from Word, you need to reference the Excel Application first before you can reference an Excel object (workbook, worksheet, range...).

Answer (score 0):

Even if this maybe a bit late answer, to succesfully open a word document from Excel (assuming this is what you are doing), you need to do the following:

1. First, you need to reference the object model of MS Word in Excel (e.g., Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library), under Tools -> References
2. Next, in your code, create an instance of the Word application:

```vb
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

I would recommend additionally the following options:

```
WordApp.Visible = False
WordApp.Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = False
```

3. After that you can open word documents, but you must always make sure that you reference the proper Word object (i.e., WordApp), so taking your example:

```
Dim mDoc As Word.Document
Set mDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(filePath)
```

BTW, the same approach would apply if you were doing if the other way around, i.e., opening Excel files from a MS Word application.

4. When you're done processing files, I recommend also quitting the Word application, i.e., using something like this:

```
If Not WordApp Is Nothing Then
    WordApp.Quit False
    Set WordApp = Nothing
End If
```

Final tip: you will have problems if there is already an instance of Word running in the background. Make sure in the Task Manager that no instance of MS Word is running before running such code.